# Reading range from std::array

Tags: c++, templates, stdarray

How can I accept a std::array  which might have  a different dimension? This should be known at compile-time but the following won't work

```
template<int n>
void read_interval(size_t start, size_t end, std::array<n, char>& dest)
```

I also know that end-start == n so that might be somehow templated either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such code compiles, you should use `size_t` instead of `int` as template parameter

```
#include <array>

template<size_t n>
void read_interval(size_t start, size_t end, std::array<char, n>& dest)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> arr1;

    read_interval(0, 10, arr1);

    std::array<char, 8> arr2;

    read_interval(0, 8, arr2);
}
```

end if `n` is always equal `end` you can just use `n` inside `read_interval` as ordinary constant.

Answer (score 1):

You have the template arguments for `std::array` the wrong way round and the non-type argument is a `std::size_t`, not an `int`:

```
template<std::size_t n>
void read_interval(size_t start, size_t end, std::array<char,n>& dest)
{
    //...
}
```

You can't statically ensure that `end - start == n` as `start` and `end` are runtime values. If you really need that static assurance, you'll need to make them template parameters, otherwise you can use a runtime assert for debug mode or carry out a check and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to template the size argument, just like you did. Except you've swapped the order of the template parameters of `std::array` which is why it doesn't work.